# In Daniel 2:34, Does the word אֶבֶן Stone symbolize אב Father and בֶן֙ Son : merging together as one אֶ֙בֶן֙ Stone?

Tags: hebrew, daniel, authorial-intent

In Daniel 2:34-45, Does the word  אֶבֶן Stone in hebrew symbolize אב Father and בֶן֙ Son : merging together as one אֶ֙בֶן֙ Stone to begin God's kingdom on earth?

Comment: What would make you think that could be the case? Do you subscribe to some esoteric theory of language?

Comment: I love this interpretation.  You would love to read the Talmud and other Midrash where the structure of language is both discovered and created.  The meanings of the letters.  The Alpha and Omega is the bounds on the alphabet, and Jesus is the Word, the indwelling divine principle of language which orders and structures the world.  Your question (type) has ancient roots.  I don’t know about this specific take.  I recommend a book “The Name” by Rabbi Mark Sameth which talks about the history of the name of God in VERY similar ways to what you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

That is a creative observation, and is the type of teaching common in old rabbinical commentaries. Whether it is *true* or not is not something that we can say, because you are asking a question about spiritual etymologies.

I will say that this lemma, אֶ֫בֶן, occurs 272 times in the Old Testament and means "unhewn" stone, so it is a symbol of Christ. It occurs also in references to altars which also need to made from unhewn stone, and this is why it occurs in Daniel, since that stone is also unhewn. God made it very clear that only these stones could be used as altars of sacrifice. Other places where אֶ֫בֶן occurs:

Psalm 118.22:
"The *stone* the builders rejected has become the chief cornerstone."

Gen 28.22:
"And this *stone* that I have set up as a pillar shall be the house of God, and of all that you give to me I will certainly give a tenth to you."

Gen 49.24:
"But his bow remained in a steady position; his arms were made agile by the hands of the Mighty One of Jacob. From there is the Shepherd, the *Rock* of Israel."

Deut 9.11:
"And then at the end of forty days and forty nights, Yahweh gave me the two tablets of *stone*, the tablets of the covenant."

Deut 27.6:
"You must build the altar of your God with unhewn *stones*, and you shall sacrifice on it burnt offerings to Yahweh your God."

Joshua 8.32:
"And there Joshua wrote on the *stones* a copy of the law of Moses, which he had written, in the presence of the Israelites."

(All references in LEB.)

I think with these types of word pictures, it's not a question of right or wrong, but as a device to convey a message, and the message is what is right or wrong. These explanations in which a word is broken up can be great teaching and memory tools, but I wouldn't worry too much about whether they are "true".

Also be aware that every symbol has multiple interpretations. The notion of Christ as a "stone" is uncontroversial, but when people are stoned to death, for example, we don't keep pushing this symbol. Similarly gold represent righteousness, but when people make idols of gold and stone (Ex 39.26), or are said to have a heart of stone (Ezekiel 11.19) we do not consider that to be a metaphor for Christ and righteousness.

Usually there are many interpretations and you need to understand the context to pick the right ones.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting observation - also an innovative theory that is not supported by the facts.  The word אֶבֶן (eben) is an Aramaic word which occurs only eight times in the OT as follows:

- Literal rock, Ezra 5:8, 6:4, Dan 6:17
- As a symbol/metaphor of God's eternal kingdom, Dan 2:34, 35, 45
- As the material of an idol of a pagan (false) god, Dan 5:4, 23.

Thus, we find that אֶבֶן (eben) is never used of God or the God-head but as a symbol of God's eternal kingdom.  But more damaging to the theory is that this word describes the material of a pagan idol or image.

However, the equivalent Hebrew word, אֶבֶן (eben) occurs 273 times.  In almost all cases it ised as a literal stoine or sone material compsing something leteral, ege, the stone tables of the 10 commandments. Only very rarely is it used as as a metaphor of YHWH as follows:

- Isaiah 28:16; So this is what the Sovereign LORD says: "See, I lay a stone in Zion, a tested stone, a precious cornerstone for a sure foundation; the one who relies on it will never be stricken with panic.  Quoted in  Rom 9:33, 10:11, and 1 Peter 2:6.
- Psalm 118:22, 23 - The stone the builders rejected has become the cornerstone. This is from the LORD, and it is marvelous in our eyes.  Quoted in  Matt 21:42, Mark 12:10, Luke 20:17, Acts 4:11, and 1 Peter 2:7

Contrast this with another Hebrew word צוּר (stur) which is frequently used as a metaphor of YHWH in the OT such as: 2 Sam 23:3, Isa 17:10, 30:29, Ps 31:3, 62:3, 7, 8, 71:3, 89:27, 94:1, 22, Deut 32:15, etc.